# Create folder based on security group member

Tags: powershell, file-sharing

I am having a bit of a block wit what I am trying to do. I am looking to create a folder structure that will generate on a schedule based on the members of a group. This will be done via powershell to allow me to add additional permissions the way I need.

So the script will run and check to see if any %folder% exists that related to %username% and if one does not exist it will create the %folder% for the %username% based off the members of GroupA.

My question is... How do I get powershell to check against the group member? would this be simply using get-adgroupmember or would this be something a bit more complex? I am not looking for a script to be written but an example of how to make that would be helpful. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are correct. A recommended way for getting members of a group is by using the `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet.

Comment: right but I could use that to create a folder like C:\temp\%username% by evoking the get-adgroupmember cmdlet?

Comment: sure, something like this maybe. `Get-ADGroupMember "SalesTeam" | ForEach-Object {md "C:\temp\$($_.samaccountname)" | out-null}` That would create a folder for each user in the group. It ignores folders that already exist. If you wanted to remove folders for users that are no longer in the group, you would have to use Compare-Object or something like that to get a list of folders whose names are not in that group.

Comment: Nice that is kind of what I am looking for, little more detailed but that gets me out of scripter block. Appreciate the help on that, first time I ever needed to pull the accounts from a group to make a folder before.